# Do Lambdas(AWS) stop making sense after a certain number of functions?

Tags: aws, serverless

I am working on a project and created multiple lambda functions and now I am thinking about whether I made the correct decision to go this route.

**Reasons I chose lambda:**

- The App will have **spiky traffic** and almost no traffic at some times, so it is cost-effective
- It seemed like it would be **less stressful to update particular functions** because I know other functions are not touched and would not break the entire app (creates a setup similar to microservices)
- All APIs on my app are under timeout limits of lambdas so **no long-running functions**

**Reasons I am doubting it now:**

- It's **difficult to share logic between lambdas** like common utility functions and constants, I am using layers but that works fine if I don't have to update the layers too often as I have to upload it manually
- **Version control** : There is an option to create versions(it's like build tagging) but no easy way to actually create a repository and deploy on changes, this makes it difficult to check what could have gone wrong during a release. I could use AWS CodePipeline, CodeBuild and a trigger using EventBridge that produces SAM template and deploys to lambda using CloudFormation, this solution would work but I don't like how many applications it uses in between to achieve this. And not having version control will make the project unmanageable.

All this has made me think **whether lambdas are not great if you have lots of functions** and would be better off with a server that always runs and is tempting me to extract all function code and put it on a server. Lambdas are a no-brainer if you have few functions that would rarely run but is it practical to create full applications with multiple APIs?

**Update:**
This question has received multiple good answers and it's either of these two

- **Lambdas are not that great as people make it seem** : I do agree with this now, when I was starting out it felt great as to how fast I was able to prototype and run things that can scale reasonably.
- **Your CI/CD is not properly configured or use the serverless framework and all the problems could be solved** : Well, this is also true as I also mentioned in my question on one of the possible ways to achieve this. But this does mean that Lambdas do not work for larger projects out of the box and you would need significant abstraction on top of it. Now that I think of it, I don't know why it didn't hit me earlier because it's so obvious now.

For now, I have decided to use lambdas initially and will eventually move the code to servers(because initially, lambdas won't even cost as much as a load balancer). For larger projects, I would say that lambdas are great for prototyping quickly or event-based background processes like step functions but if you have worked with servers before then you will be always questioning yourself when you start adding functions after another.

Comment: there are some downvotes which is fine, but can anyone please comment on what is wrong here? I am looking for any input here positive or negative

Comment: I think they are downvoting because the answer to this question is a matter of opinion. Perhaps it would help to break down or quantify the problem, if you can. For example, you could estimate the TCO (total cost of ownership) for both scenarios, then choose the cheaper option. If you think lambdas will be more work to maintain, or maintaining a dedicated server will require additional resource, include those costs in the each of the two estimates before you compare them.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for the comment. I do get that it is an opinion question because there is nothing stopping me to create multiple functions. My main question is whether there is a certain number after which lamdas don't make sense to maintain. Like if you have more than X lambdas in your app, then you should stay away from it. 

I'll try to reframe the question to make it more focussed

Comment: I feel something fundamental is missing either about the CI/CD process or IaC configuration management -- specifically it sounds as if the SAM templates are generated automatically from an EventBridge trigger?  If so, something feels awfully wrong about that.   Those templates represent the version of your infrastructure so they should be stored in source control  (that's typically how the IaC would be tagged/versioned, though personally I'm not a fan of using SAM templates directly, I find Terraform to be a far more more developer-friendly alternative).

Answer (score 4):

Working with Lambdas really requires some deployment automation tooling to manage all of these things for you. At my last job, we used [Serverless Framework](https://www.serverless.com/), but after a year I was starting to feel like it was holding back my productivity.

If I had to choose tooling today, I'd probably go for Terraform or the [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/getting_started.html).

Serverless was interesting. I learned a lot, especially about DevOps. But I don't miss that codebase. There were a number of reasons it was becoming a dumpster fire, and Lambda played a minor part in several of them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your last sentence a bit, perhaps with a couple of examples?

Comment: Certainly! They were all essentially process and people issues, but Lambda presented more opportunities for them to occur.

We had tons of duplicate code people would add and start copying and pasting it throughout a ton of functions instead of adding it to our common library. Our TypeScript bundles sometimes grew insanely large to the point where we couldn't deploy them. Integrating with IoT hardware made testing really, really hard. Poor database performance because DB connections were mismanaged. People jacking up timeouts to ten minutes instead of diagnosing issues properly.

Comment: @ScottSimontis That is exactly what I see happening to me, the way lambdas are implemented invites so many bad design choices. Amazon markets lambdas like they are good for almost everything(this is why I started using it) but I don't think it is unless you have major abstractions on top of it to make the project manageable.

Comment: @AKT It's an axiom of software engineering that any project will grow more complex over time. 99% of the articles I see about serverless show one or two functions, no one talks about things like "So you are now your company's DevOps engineer in addition to your full time job."

Then again, microservices and container orchestration have plenty of pain points and frustration as well. I haven't lost all faith in Lambdas, but they aren't the answer to every question and you need a well-staffed team with solid AWS foundations.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambdas never made any sense.

Or perhaps I should say "serverless applications" never made any sense. Because it seems to me that's what you are doing, moving application code to lambdas for cost reasons.

As you note, actually the lambdas all run on instances that get billed by the hour, so unless you have long periods of nothing running at all you hardly save any money over always having a tiny instance up.

You also have the various complexities you outline, essentially you are forced into a nano-service++ architecture with complex orchestration problems.

Now you can in theory imagine an application where this architecture is ideal, lots of queues, events and mini functions all working together, but in practice its a bit like functional programming. Nice in theory, but difficult to apply to standard "line of business" applications.

In summary, only use Lambdas where you have a specific need for them. Don't use them because the billing model appears different.

Comment: +1. I had the same realization with a hobby project a year ago. I started building it on googles lamdas and when I started writing the fourth I asked myself the same question as the OP. Now the whole thing (including DB) is running in one VM at a smaller hoster, for a third of the cost.

Comment: A great many apps have long periods of nothing running! You do NOT get billed by the hour - that is simply wrong - you get billed by the millisecond and megabyte IIRC. One lambda call costs one lambda call - even if Amazon secretly has to download the lambda code to some instance and start a process, you are not billed for that. Of course the trade-off is that they are more expensive if your lambda runs for a long time.

Comment: yeah "by the hour" means "by time unit" but the point is most apps that you would consider for "serverless" are web apps with user based traffic. ie they dont sit idle all day and run once on a schedule or anything like that

Comment: @Ewan But you only pay when they are running - that's the thing.

Comment: @Ewan Option 1: you pay (for example) $10/month for your app on a server - a flat rate. Option 2: you pay (for example) $0.000001 per request. If your app gets less than ten million requests per month, option 2 is better. Also, with option 2 you have less attack surface and greater maximum concurrency.

Comment: That's the theory, in practice there are loads of downsides to lambda's and the pricing is carefully worked out so that its not cheaper for most use cases

Comment: to the recent downvoter : https://www.primevideotech.com/video-streaming/scaling-up-the-prime-video-audio-video-monitoring-service-and-reducing-costs-by-90

Answer (score 1):

It's true that lambdas can save hosting costs for low- and medium-traffic apps.

You don't have to have a zillion separate lambdas and a deployment nightmare for your little app, though. There is no technical restriction that prevents you from putting an entire monolithic app, which branches to different code depending on the type of request, into a single lambda. Don't be fooled by the marketing. Of course, it might make sense to split up large apps or apps with lots of traffic.

You also don't need to version-control your deployed lambdas, only your source code. If you use EC2 do you version-control your EC2 instances? Of course not. You may version-control the code which creates and configures them - but not the instances themselves, because that makes no sense.

If you only have one lambda, or a few lambdas, you can make a short script (on your own computer) that uses the AWS CLI to deploy them all.

Don't try to make a serious app using the online editor in the AWS console - since (as you pointed out) you don't get version control, or any of the other features you want when programming source code (such as auto-complete).

Comment: +1 to that part "There is no technical restriction that prevents you from putting an entire monolithic app, which branches to different code depending on the type of request, into a single lambda." - that was my first architectural decision after the client insisted on using Lambda. We use more of a microservices approach to have the best of two worlds: a manageable environment (6 services made of 20 lambdas instead of several hundred in a typical Lambda architecture of this scale), and good integration with other AWS products. Plus if we will decide to stop using Lambda we are quite prepared.

Answer (score -1):

> whether lambdas are not great if you have lots of functions

The reasons you state are not linked to number of functions or code size as elaborated below.

> It's difficult to share logic between lambdas

Not a Serverless specific problem. Micro-services too have the same issue. Multi-module monoliths too have shared libraries. When you break logic into pieces, common logic has to live somewhere. One pattern would be to refactor out shared logic in a library/package. Then base each function/service upon it.

Whether it is 20 functions or 200, shared logic has to be refactored out.

> Version control...but no easy way to actually create a repository and deploy on changes

Again, a Dev-ops problem. Pick any competent CI-CD tool and automate it to spit out packages/images for ALL functions/service (changed or not) per change committed. All tagged with the same build number and deployed together. The environment should represent a single snapshot of the code base, not a mix of selectively updated and deployed components.

The automated script that can build 20 functions can also build and deploy 200.

In the end, it is not code base size that presents a true hindrance. In fact you are not limited to Lambda and its tools for server-less computing. Stacks like [Knative](https://knative.dev/docs/) exist that allow shared base images, service versioning etc.

Comment: While this is mostly true, it's also a rant about Lambda and serverless which doesn't actually answer the question.